# Trying to pass variable values from JavaScript to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass some values from JavaScript to PHP using jQuery/AJAX. I have the following "simplified" code, not sure what is that I am doing wrong. There seems to be quite a few similar questions/answers in StackOverflow, but none of the them are really helping.

HTML:

```
<div>
<a href="#" id="text-id">Send text</a>
<textarea id="source1" name="source1" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
<textarea id="source2" name="source2" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#text-id").click(function() {
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: 'text.php',
data: {source1: "some text", source2: "some text 2"}
});
});
```

PHP (text.php):

```
<?php 

$src1= $_POST['source1'];  
$src2= $_POST['source2'];     

echo $src1; 
echo $src2;

?>
```

The problem:  Nothing is happening...no errors..nothing. I don't see the values of 'source1' and 'source2' showing up in the PHP echo statements.

Comment: first include jquery file

Comment: that is already there...in the HTML head. I just didn't show it here.

Comment: Please - give us a clue! What is happening, or not happening? Do you see an error message?

Comment: see updated answer POST be captical

Comment: Ok - what's in the server logs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include a [success handler](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) in your AJAX call:

```
$("#text-id").on( 'click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'text.php',
        data: {
            source1: "some text",
            source2: "some text 2"
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
});
```

and in your console, you'll receive:

```
some textsome text 2
```

Do make sure that both the `test.php` and your html source files are in same directory.

Comment: Hi, the JavaScript console does show "some textsome text 2". but for some reason I don't see any of the PHP echo statements. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: @Gandalf I'm not sure I understand your question. You want the PHP source code to be sent back?

Comment: yes...it is supposed to do something and then send the control back to the JavaScript. At least that is what I am trying to achieve. In this case the "echo $src1" statements is not doing anything. I was expecting it to populate the page with the $src1 value.

Comment: The `$src1` value is `some text` and `$src2` is `some text 2`. It __IS__ populating those data

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#text-id").click(function(e) {// because #text-id is an anchor tag so stop its default behaivour
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",// see also here
url: 'text.php',// and this path will be proper
data: {
       source1: "some text",
       source2: "some text 2"}
}).done(function( msg )
      {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );// see alert is come or not
     });
});
```

reference **[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Comment: Thanks, but this did not help.