# PHP+Ajax Passing input keyword for live search

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search, live

I already asked this, but I guess it was too abstract and all I got was suggestions to use DataTables plugin, however I want to do this live search manually.

I would like to know how can I pass a keyword (and how to create it for sending )from the input box to the `findUser();` function with MySQL search query on every `.keyup` and refresh the shown content in `#theContent`.

Right now it correctly finds the people with ".com" because in users.ajax.php `findUser('.com');` function has ".com" keyword manually written in instead of using the input box.

Currently, index.php:

```
<input id="search">
    <table border="1" BORDERCOLOR=black>
    <thead> 
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>LastName</th><th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="theContent">

    </tbody>

    </table>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadUser(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'users.ajax.php'

        }).done(function(data){
            var HTML = '';
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            $.each(data['usersData'], function(key, val){
                HTML += getSingleUserLine(val);
            });


            $('#theContent').html(HTML);

            $( '#search' ).keyup(function() {   // need it to send the keyword here and refresh the results?
                 alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
            });

        });
        }

    function getSingleUserLine(data){
        if(data){
            var string = '';

            string = '<tr><td>'+data.fname+'</td><td>'+data.lname+'</td><td>'+data.email+'</td></tr>';

            return string;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
            loadUser();
    });
    </script>
```

in users.ajax.php:

```
$return = array();

    include('db.class.php');
    include('user.class.php');

    $DB = new DB(XXXXXXXX)
    $USER = new User(); 

    $data = $USER->findUser('.com');


    $return['usersData'] = $data;

    echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: What's the variable going from the jQuery/AJAX to the PHP that holds the search keyword?

Comment: have you atleast searched how to pass a variable through ajax to php?

Comment: it's inadvisable to use event-listeners like `$( '#search' ).keyup(function() { }` inside custom functions. because the event-listener is not working till the function is called once - and you also are rebinding the listener, if you call the function again. and so on..

Comment: There is no variable yet, I wasn't entirely clear, I would like to know how to create it (use what's in the 'input' box).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to pass variable values from JavaScript to PHP using AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462649/trying-to-pass-variable-values-from-javascript-to-php-using-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to start from the ground up, and found quite an easy solution:

I edited the loadUser() like so :

```
function loadUser(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'users.ajax.php',
            data: { 'keyword': $('#search').val() },


        }).done(function(data){
            var HTML = '';
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            $.each(data['usersData'], function(key, val){
                HTML += getSingleUserLine(val);
            });

            $('#theContent').html(HTML);

        });

    }
```

then in the end:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


            $( '#search' ).keyup(function() {
                 loadUser();
            });

    });
```

users.ajax.php:

```
$data = $USER->findUser($_GET['keyword']);
```

Thanks for Your time trying to help me out though!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `$_GET` parameter to send the input keyword from the input field to ajax.php.

Call loadUser when the keyUp happens:

```
$( '#search' ).keyup(function() {   
                 loadUser();
            });
```

Do this with the loadUser method:

```
function loadUser(){

     var searchval = $("#search").val();

     $.ajax({
        url: 'users.ajax.php?term='+searchval;

    })
```

In ajax.php, use the $_GET['term'] to access the field value:

```
 $data = $USER->findUser($_GET['term']);
```

Comment: Nothing happens :( replacing keyup's loadUser() with alert(); shows that it doesn't react. Where am I supposed to call the keyup? at the bottom from the $(document).ready(function)()?

Comment: In the answer you posted, this is what you seem to have done. You don't need to call keyup, the search field is already tied to that. you might have missed a couple of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
     function loadUser(serachWord){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'users.ajax.php',
            data: { variableForSearch: serachWord }

        }).done(function(data){
            var HTML = '';
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            $.each(data['usersData'], function(key, val){
                HTML += getSingleUserLine(val);
            });


            $('#theContent').html(HTML);



        });
        }

 function getSingleUserLine(data){
        if(data){
            var string = '';

            string = '<tr><td>'+data.fname+'</td><td>'+data.lname+'</td><td>'+data.email+'</td></tr>';

            return string;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
     $( '#search' ).keyup(function() {   // need it to send the keyword here and refresh the results?
                 loadUser($( '#search' ).val());
            });


    });
```

your php code:

```
$return = array();

include('db.class.php');
include('user.class.php');

$DB = new DB(XXXXXXXX)
$USER = new User(); 

$data = $USER->findUser($_POST['variableForSearch']);


$return['usersData'] = $data;

echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I replaced the $(document).ready(function) keyup with alert and it doesn't react.